What is the current equivalent of CircuitQNN?
I have a qiskit QNN code and I want to update some part of this code and use it in my project. In my project, I train and test a QNN that simply classifies images. However, I couldn't find what I could use instead of the CircuitQNN part of the code. This is the part of the code I need:
nqubits=6
num_inputs=256
qc = QuantumCircuit(nqubits)

# Encoding
param_x=[];
for i in range(num_inputs):
    param_x.append(Parameter('x'+str(i)))
for i in range(8):
    param_x.append(np.pi/2)


feature_map = encoding(qc,param_x,22)


# Optimzing circuit PQC
param_y=[];
for i in range(nqubits*2):
    param_y.append(Parameter('θ'+str(i)))

ansatz=circuit15(qc,param_y)

qc.append(feature_map, range(nqubits))
qc.append(ansatz, range(nqubits))

qnn2 = CircuitQNN(qc, input_params=feature_map.parameters, weight_params=ansatz.parameters, 
                  interpret=parity, output_shape=2, quantum_instance=qi)
initial_weights = 0.1*(2*np.random.rand(qnn2.num_weights) - 1)

What i done is:
np.random.seed(3)


nqubits=6
num_inputs=256

qc = QuantumCircuit(nqubits)

qc.append(feature_map, range(nqubits))
qc.append(ansatz, range(nqubits))

param_x = [Parameter(f'x{i}') for i in range(num_inputs)]
param_y = [Parameter(f'\u03b8{i}') for i in range(nqubits * 2)]  

qnn2 = circuitQNN(
    circuit=qc,
    input_params=feature_map.parameters,
    weight_params=ansatz.parameters,
    interpret=parity,
    output_shape=2,
    quantum_instance=qi
)

torch.manual_seed(3)
initial_weights = 0.1 * (2 * np.random.rand(qnn2.num_weights) - 1)

